# Is it possible put in directives in v-html directive?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm making some web features. But I have one problem.
I wanted to create several html structures that added vue directives with v-html, but I couldn't.
So, How can I render vue directives with v-html?

Of course I know this can cause xss vulnerability, but I will filter any critical tags so I don't care.

please share your tips!!

1. I already use Vue.compile function. But, it supports only full build and this don't match with my case.
2. `<button @click="go()">go</button>`
   this is what i want to make using v-html.
   But @click directive is not rendered...

**this is `App.vue` result**

[image: Imgur]

But go button couldn't call go function.

---

**App.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-model="name" />
    <p v-html="name"></p>
    <!-- Below tag is what i want to make using v-html -->
    <!-- <button @click="go()">gogo</button> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data:function(){
    return {
      name:'',
    }
  },
  methods:{
    go(){
      alert('hi');
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Do you just need event listeners or are there other parts of Vue syntax that you need inside your `v-html`?

Comment: Try with `v-on` something like `v-on="{click: go()}"`

Comment: @skirtle I want to use more directives not only `v-on` event listener inside `v-html` :)

Comment: @Michael thank you for sharing tip ! But `<button v-on="{click: go()}">go</button>` also didn't work :,(

Comment: If I understand, you would put dynamic Vue template '<button @click="go()">gogo</button>' inside name var, and render it?

Comment: If it is the case, take a look on this JSFiddle exemple based on :is directive for dynamic component, it might help you to do what you're trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/jexzywua/1/

Comment: @Sackey Correct!! Thank you soooooo much !!!

Comment: @leesh Nice, I posted the answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you try to achieve is to compile a string as a Vue.js template component. You can use the ':is' directive to refer a dynamic component, and bind your local stringified data and functions from this dynamic component to your main Vue instance or component.

i.e:

```html
<div id="app">
  <div :is="dynamicComponent"></div>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    template: '<button @click="sharedFun()">{{ sharedValue }}</button>',
    sharedValue: 'this is a shared value'
  },

  computed: {
    dynamicComponent() {
        let f_sharedFunWithContext = typeof this.sharedFunWithContext === 'function'
        ? this.sharedFunWithContext
        : () => {}

        return {
        template: this.template,

        // redirect every shared data here
        data: () => {
            return {
            sharedValue: this.sharedValue
          }
        },

        // redirect every shared methods here
        methods: {
            sharedFun: () => {
            return this.sharedFun()
          },

          sharedFunWithContext(params) {
            // 'this' contains dynamic component context
            return f_sharedFunWithContext(params);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    sharedFun() {
        alert('do some secure stuff on root instance')
    },

    sharedFunWithContext() {
        alert('do some secure stuff on root instance')
    }
  }
})
```

JSFiddle implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/jexzywua/1/

Comment: In vue3, I need to improvise by adding. 
```<template>
  <component v-bind:is="dynamicComponent"></component>
</template>```